# What's the preferred way to include a library in a cmake c++ project?

Tags: c++, cmake

I've built the libfreenect2 library, now I want to include it in my c++ project. Before, I've included some libraries with cmake like this:

```
# Include OpenCV
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
target_link_libraries( ${PROJECT_NAME} ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

This means that the library has to be properly "installed" to my system for cmake to find it, correct?

However, this time I need to "manually" include the necessary files and directories to my project. But I don't have a clue on how the "correct" way to do it.

Been following [this tutorial](https://cmake.org/cmake-tutorial/), but it's confusing how I have to add library, include directories, add subdirectories (why is it suddenly "add" and not "include"), link libraries... Is the terminology inconsistent, or is the approach always really this messy? I can't see why it wouldn't be enough to just express the library directory **ONCE** then cmake should figure out what to do with it? Sorry about my ignorance.

Anyways, what's the preferred steps to include a customly built library?

This is my current attempt, which (when I try to compile my project) yields "cannot find -lfreenect2"

```
project(kinect-test)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
aux_source_directory(. SRC_LIST)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_LIST})

# Include directories
include_directories ($ENV{HOME}/freenect2/include)

# Find freenect package
set(freenect2_DIR $ENV{HOME}/freenect2/lib/cmake/freenect2)
find_package(freenect2 REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries (${PROJECT_NAME} freenect2)
```

Comment: I can't tell you the generally preferred way, but what I do is have a library of cmake scripts which download and build the required libraries in the build tree. I've started an open-source project if you'd like to help! https://github.com/madmongo1/sanity

Comment: Thanks, but adding a library of cmake scripts to find my libraries makes it no less confusing for me. I'd love to help out on your project, but I guess at this stage I would probably do more harm than good. Maybe later, when I understand how to actually use cmake...

Comment: Command `find_package(freenect2 REQUIRED)` sets **variables**, describing the library. Variable `freenect2_LIBRARIES` contains libraries to link with, variable `freenect2_INCLUDE_DIRS` contains directories where its hearers resides. You need to use these variables in your script: `include_directories(${freenect2_INCLUDE_DIRS})`, `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${freenect2_LIBRARIES})`. BTW, you do exactly the same for OpenCV.

Comment: Did as you suggested (see edit3 of post). Still, same error.

Comment: Possible duplicate to [Building with libfreenect2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37533866/building-with-libfreenect2). For an CMake enabled project like `freenect2` what you are doing is correct. Just move the `find_package()` command to the top (behind your `project()` command). The `freenect2_` variables are only defined after the `find_package()` command. And do `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${freenect2_LIBRARIES})`.

Comment: EDIT: Thanks, but note I have to use `set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH} $ENV{HOME}/freenect2/lib/cmake/freenect2)` before I use `find_package` so cmake will find it. Even though the question you refer to solves my particular problem with this, I disagree that this is a question duplicate. My question is what's the preferred steps to include a customly built library? which, in principle, doesn't really have anything to do with libfreenect2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing:

- Set cmake prefix to enable it to find the config file (named "freenect2Config.cmake")
- "Find" the "package", which makes cmake run the "find script"
- Include directories to get headers
- Link library files

CMakeLists.txt

```
project(kinect-test)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
aux_source_directory(. SRC_LIST)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_LIST})

# Set cmake prefix path to enable cmake to find freenect2
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH} $ENV{HOME}/freenect2/lib/cmake/freenect2)

# Find freenect, to set necessary variables
find_package(freenect2 REQUIRED)

# Include directories to get freenect headers
include_directories($ENV{HOME}/freenect2/include)

# Link freenect libraries with the project
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${freenect2_LIBRARIES})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a search path that can find the given library. I assume the file `libfreenect.so` (or `libfreenect.a`) is located in `/path/to/freenect` - please edit as appropriate, possibly using a variable. Above your `target_link_libraries` command add the command:

```
link_directories(/path/to/freenect)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've done what you suggested (see my question edit). I still get the same error: `cannot find -lfreenect2`

Comment: Can you set `cmake` to verbose mode and share the the final compiler linking line (one that probably goes something like `g++ ... -o kinect-test ...`?

Comment: This one? `/usr/bin/c++      CMakeFiles/kinect-test.dir/main.cpp.o  -o kinect-test -rdynamic -lfreenect2`